# Is there a simple closed curve which is not rectifiable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a loop such that $\gamma$ is injective on $(0,1]$. (So the image of the curve is a simple close curve is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Is $\gamma$ rectifiable in this case?

How do I prove it? If this is not true, what is a counterexample?

Comment: I believe that from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Curves_with_infinite_length) it follows that a graph of $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ with additional path from $0$ to let's say $z = (1/\pi, 0)$ is a counterexample (as a simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: You could also use a closed variant of the Koch curve as an counter example I think.

Comment: Best link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake - clear example of a simple closed curve.